# How do Anonymous functions work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand anonymous functions but having a hard time.  The function below is an anonymous function but I'm not sure how it would get called or used.  I have looked all over the web but have not gotten a good explanation of how/when to use it. Please help.

```
    var area1 = (function() {
    var width = 5;
    var height = 2;

    return width*height;
}());
```

Thanks for any clarification that can be provided.

Comment: The function is defined and called afterwards. That's because there's `()` after the function's body `{...}`. I'm not sure what else is there to explain.

Comment: Here's another helpful link that I found: http://esbueno.noahstokes.com/post/77292606977/self-executing-anonymous-functions-or-how-to-write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an immediately executed function expression. The function is defined, then executed right away (by the `()` after it).

The code has the same effect as:

```
var area1 = 10;
```

You can't use the function after that statement, because it only exists as an intermediate value, and the variable `area1` is assigned the result of executing the function.